# Add new jquery kanban item with the name and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-widgets

My kanban is composed of 2 columns, and each column has several items (representing task) :
taskId on the top, and task name on the bottom part of the item.
I have selected task from database (taskId and taskName).
An ajax query slect the task from the database and the response is the new list of task.
This list is a json.
I set this json to the localData of my kanban source.
The role is displayed in the item, but instead of having is name, nothing is displayed.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Task/viewTask",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST", dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ employeeId: empId }),
    success: function (data) {
      var selectedmaper = null;
       for (var i = 0; i < colMapper.length; i++) {
           if (colMapper[i].empID == empId) {
               selectedmaper = colMapper[i];
               break;
           }

       }
       for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
           debugger;

           var taskName = (data[i].taskId).toString();
           resourcesSourceData.push({ id: data[i].taskId, name: taskName });
           var resourceId = data[i].taskId;
           $('#kanban1').jqxKanban('addItem', { status: selectedmaper.autoID, text: data[i].description, tags: "task", color: "#5dc3f0", resourceId: resourceId });

       }


    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wed3e.png